# How to Handle Dynamic Priority Updates in Firestore

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, database-design

I'm managing a list of 10,000+ items in Firestore, each with a dynamic priority that frequently changes. Initially, I stored items in an array within a single document, but this approach struggles with performance as the dataset grows, especially when updating priorities.

```
{
  "items": [
    { "id": "item1", "priority": 1, "title": "Item 1" },
    { "id": "item2", "priority": 2, "title": "Item 2" },
     // More items...
  ]
}
```

Issue: Updating an item's priority means reading and writing the entire list, leading to performance issues (for example, if I need to set `"item2"` to `"priority": 1` I need to read the whole document, update `"item2"`, then update `"item1"` to `"priority": 2` and override the whole document with new values.)

Attempted Solutions:

Moving each item to its own document to individually update priorities.
Considering transactions for atomic updates but concerned about performance with large-scale adjustments.

Questions:
What's the best practice for structuring and managing dynamic priorities in Firestore efficiently?
How can I handle atomic updates and maintain consistency with minimal performance impact?

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: If updating the fields is not possible, what would be the recommended collection structure to achieve this goal?

Comment: If you want to update an item in an array field, it's a requirement to read the document, update the array in memory, then write the modified array back to the document.  There is no way to make that more efficient, and is a very common task.  Moving the data to multiple documents will only make it less efficient, as you will end up reading and writing multiple documents. Firestore will never internally modify data that you didn't explicitly set yourself.